# How to Webform fields in table format in drupal7

Tags: drupal

i wanted to show the webform fields in table format how can i do this in drupal 7.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to override the theme with a [hook_theme_registry_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme_registry_alter/7).

Though I would actually recommend just doing this with css. Webform will have all the classes necessary outputted by default. You can just set a width and float labels left and field right and clear on each form item.